# JavaScript - Reading URLs from a file and saving them as elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, file, filereader

I have very little javascript skills and I would like to pass lines of a file as String arguments to a pre-written function. Basically what I want to do is read a file in this type of format, with each url on its own line:

`www.url1.com
 www.url2.com`

...And so on

How can I read a local file and save each line to a String array?

Thank you very much, and let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far. A working fiddle would be best. So far you have not demonstrated any attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: also, are you trying to "read in" the file through the FileReader, or as a response to an AJAX request? aka, is it a local file or a remote file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by looking at [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList), [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), and [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) web APIs. Note that your browser may not support these APIs, but most modern browsers should. You can check for their existence by looking for their properties in the `window` object.

I have added example code below with comments.

HTML:

```
<input id="f" type="file">
```

JavaScript:

```
// This event listener is triggered when you open a file with the input button.
document.getElementById('f').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  // Get File from FileList.
  // Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList
  var f = this.files[0]; // event.target.files[0] works too

  // Need an instance of this API for asynchronous file I/O.
  var fr = new FileReader();

  // First create a function to handle the "onload" event.
  fr.onload = function(event) {
    // FileReader.result holds file contents
    // Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result
    var textInFile = this.result; // event.target.result works too
    // String.prototype.split with newline character argument
    var urls = textInFile.split('\n');
    console.log(urls);
  }

  // This performs asynchronous I/O and eventually triggers the "onload" event.
  // Default encoding is UTF-8.
  // Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText
  fr.readAsText(f);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the HTML5 File API.

For an example see this blog post: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api

Although the limitation is, this must be used through a

```
<input type="file">
```

So you cannot just read arbitrary files, without the user knowing.