# How to split list of words into array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a .txt file that has the entire dictionary in it. It is separated so that each line is a new word:

EX:

```
this
is  
what
it
looks
like
```

I need help in putting all of these words into a single array. I am new to Javascript so give me a break if this is a dumb question.

Comment: How does JavaScript get the text file? Are you using Node? Running in a browser?

Comment: I also need help with the import.

Comment: @kwolff7 Sounds like you need to learn Javascript, and you're expecting us to teach you everything.

Comment: Is the file really double-spaced like that? Or did you add the extra spaces to prevent SO from merging the lines?

Comment: I double spaced to make it so it wasn't a straight line

Comment: @Barmar do you have any suggestions of where to learn more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Reading URLs from a file and saving them as elements in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655538/javascript-reading-urls-from-a-file-and-saving-them-as-elements-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a regex to "split" your string on the newline (`\n`), like so:

```
var dictionary = "this\nis\nwhat\nit\nlooks\nlike"
dictionary.split(/[\n]+/g)

// -> ["this", "is", "what", "it", "looks", "like"]
```

You can learn more about regex and play with it at http://regexr.com/3d4rr

Comment: what about reading from a .txt file?